# Include js and css in wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress, I am trying to include js and css files and also jQuery to a widget that I create, my code right now is

```
<?php
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
            // Base ID of your widget
            'my_widget', 

            // Widget name will appear in UI
            __('My Widget', 'my_widget_domain'), 

            // Widget description
            array( 'description' => __( 'Blah blah ', 'my_widget_domain' ), ) );
    }

        // Creating widget front-end
        // This is where the action happens
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

           //Some functionallity

        }

} // Class wpb_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'my_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/my_plugin/js/jquery/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/my_plugin/css/my_theme.css">
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/my_plugin/js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/my_plugin/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/my_plugin/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

As you can see I am including my scripts at the end of my file, I read about `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` but I am not sure where exactly is the right place to include my script.  Does the wordpress already include the jQueryUI ?

Comment: Also, Please search before posting your problem. here is your solutions. [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48445/how-to-include-javascript-file-and-css-file-in-wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48445/how-to-include-javascript-file-and-css-file-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include css and js to wordpress plugins.

In your plugin file of plugin folder add following code.

```
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url('/js/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );

    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style(){
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');

   wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
}
```

Create your script.js and style.css file to js and css directory of plugin directory.